# Microsoft Graph $top filter return inconsistent results

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

When using MS Graph the API is returning inconsistent results when using $top filter.

Here is an example using the MS Graph Explorer:

[image]

Here we can see that we are setting top to 1 element and the API is returning 8.

The query is:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts?$top=1&$count=true`

Here is the link to the graph explorer:

`https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer`

If someone is also having the same problem or the API is working well for him it will help a lot knowing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, this should be correct, because the alerts in the result are from the different providers, check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/alert-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters):

> `$top` - Returns the aggregated top results from each security API
> provider.

e.g. If you use `$top=1` and there are 8 providers in your case, then you will get 8 values, it will get one value from each provider.

If you specify only one provider via the `$filter`, then you will get only one value with `$top=1`, you can check the provider keywords [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/alert-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters).

Sample:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts?$filter=vendorInformation/provider eq 'MCAS'&$top=1&$count=true
```

[image]